# How did the Moody's cracked Foe-Glass get into the Room of Requirement?

Tags: harry-potter

If Dumbledore did not know of the Room of Requirement then how did Moody's Foe-Glass make its way into the Room?

From UK Edition page 346 'Dumbledore's Army'

> The walls were lined with wooden bookcases and instead of chairs there were large silk cushions on the floor. A set of shelves at the far end of the room carried a range of instruments such as Sneakoscopes, Secrecy Sensors and a large, cracked Foe-Glass that Harry was sure had hung, the previous year, in the fake Moody's office

Comment: the foe-glass wasnt cracked at the beginning of book 4 right? and it cracked after fake moody was confronted? simply a broken thing was probably discarded, most likely a house elves threw it away, in the room of requirements, since the house elves were all aware of it. probably by dobby himself.

Comment: All right, I knew there was a more canonical explanation! Answer updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of direct canon explanation. Some possible ones (the last one is more canon than the rest):

1. The room can summon objects from anywhere. It brought in, as your quote showed, books on DaDA, and various instruments of the trade.
2. This is Harry's theory that it was the same one. Doesn't have to be correct
3. Even if correct, we have no evidence of whether the Glass belonged to Moody or Crouch. If Crouch, it would have stayed at Hogwarts as there was no family member left alive to claim belongings. If Moody's, it may be possible that it was left behind - either because Moody was still recuperating and didn't bother, or because he didn't need it and it was broken.
4. **UPDATED** Harry nicked it from fake-Moody's office, at the same time he did the Marauder's map:

   > **HPFreak7**: How did Harry get the Marauder's Map back, when Crouch Jr. had it last?
   >   **JK Rowling replies ->** Loads of people have asked me this, I knew I should have shown Harry nipping into Moody's empty office and getting it back, but I assumed you'd all know that's what he did. Sorry! (*[JK Rowling's World Book Day Chat,
   >   March 4, 2004](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm)*)

Comment: i was looking for something more along the lines of Dumbledore or one of the other teachers putting that Foe-Glass into the room, whether it was Moody's or not. but i guess that if the room can just summon these kinda objects then thats one explanation and the other as mentioned by Himarm is possibly it was the house elves, presume clearing old stuff from teachers rooms is part of their duties